# Update a widget in mobile app on a new database record

Tags: flutter, flask, websocket, server-sent-events

I am developing an app using flutter.
The backend is in flask and the database is a nosql (mongodb).

I have a widget which shows users who have liked an article.
What I want to achieve is:

A) if user X likes an article that I am currently viewing I want to instantly see that (ie his avatar, name, doesn’t matter).

B) let’s say I am on another screen (ie settings), I want the same to happen in the background so when I go back to the article screen, to see the user that has liked the article (if that’s possible).

What I know so far is that I have to use a stream builder (flutter). This is fine, I understand how that works.

My question is how am I going to push the new server event/database record(user X likes article Y) to the app.

Should I use server sent events, websockets or there is another solution?
If sse and ws are the only solutions which one is preferable given that I’m using flask as my backend?

Almost all of the examples I have seen online are unfortunately using firebase (not all of us want to use firebase!) and none of the websocket examples mention anything about data we want to retrieve from a db.

Any reference to a helpful tutorial (no firebase!) would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm doing something similar for a chat app, i had to use `flask-socketio` to emit events from flask and `socket_io_client: ^2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0` on flutter along with `flutter_bloc` to handle my state.

Comment: Thanks. This is bidirectional communication though. In any case, do you store chat messages in a db? If yes how do you go about emitting saved messages?

Comment: I only store them in mongodb, i'm yet to get to the caching bit of my project. I have a socket endpoint to handle new messages that in turn stores them in mongo and emits the stored message back to the client as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar for a chat app, i had to use `flask-socketio` to emit events from flask and `socket_io_client: ^2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0` on flutter along with `flutter_bloc` to handle my state. I'm using the beta flutter socket_io_client because my server is using socketio 4 which is not supported by the current stable version.

**Flutter**

```dart
@injectable
class SocketBloc extends Bloc<SocketEvent, SocketState> {
  final Socket _socket;

  SocketBloc(this._socket)
      : super(SocketState.initial()) {
    on<SocketEvent>((event, emit) async {
      await event.map(
        connecting: (value) async => await _mapConnectingToState(emit, value),
        connected: (value) async => await _mapConnectToState(emit, value),
        disconnected: (value) async => await _mapDisconnectToState(emit, value),
        error: (value) async => await _mapErrorToState(emit, value),
        connect: (value) async => await _mapSocketConnectToState(emit, value),
        inquiries: (value) async => await _mapAddInquiriesToState(emit, value),
        setActiveInquiry: (value) async =>
            await _mapSetActiveInquiryToState(emit, value),
        newChatMessage: (value) async =>
            await _mapNewChatMessageToState(emit, value),
        newMessage: (value) async => await _mapNewMessageToState(emit, value),
        sendChat: (value) async => await _mapSendChatToState(emit, value),
        uploadFiles: (value) async => await _mapUploadFilesToState(emit, value),
      );
    });

    _setUpListeners();
  }

  void _setUpListeners() {
    _socket.onConnecting((data) => add(const SocketEvent.connecting()));
    _socket.onConnect((data) => add(const SocketEvent.connected()));
    _socket.onConnectError((data) => add(const SocketEvent.error()));
    _socket.onDisconnect((data) => add(const SocketEvent.disconnected()));

    _socket.on(
      Events.INQUIRIES.name,
      (data) => add(SocketEvent.inquiries(data)),
    );

    _socket.on(
      Events.NEW_CHAT.name,
      (data) => add(SocketEvent.newChatMessage(data)),
    );

    _socket.on(
      Events.NEW_MESSAGE.name,
      (data) => add(SocketEvent.newMessage(data)),
    );
  }
```

**Flask**

```py
@socketio.on(prefix)
def handle_new_message(data):
    admin = get_admin()

    if not admin:
        raise Exception("Admin not configured")

    # Get user by sid
    db_user = User.objects.get(session=request.sid)

    if not db_user:
        raise Exception("No such client")

    message = data.get('message')
    if not message:
        raise Exception("No message content")

    message_id = data.get('message_id')
    if not message_id:
        raise Exception("No message ID")

    db_message = Message.objects.get(pk=message_id)
    if not db_message:
        raise Exception("No such message")

    # TODO - Affirm that sender is owner of message

    chat = Chat(message=message,
                message_id=message_id,
                recipient=admin.uid,
                sender=db_user.uid)
    chat.save()
    emit(SocketEvents.NEW_CHAT.name, JSONEncoder().encode(clear_cls(chat.to_mongo().to_dict())))

    db_message.last_message = chat.message
    db_message.save()
    emit(SocketEvents.NEW_MESSAGE.name, JSONEncoder().encode(clear_cls(db_message.to_mongo().to_dict())))
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to include flask socket emit